# __template__() takes no arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, web.py

I am building a website using web.py as the framework.

This is what my urls is:

```
urls = (
    '/', 'index',
    '/search', 'search',
    '/book/(.*)', 'book' 
)
```

This is what the book class looks like:

```
class book:
    def GET(self, isbn):
        isbnvar = "isbn = '{0}'".format(isbn)
        book_details = db.select('books_bookdata',where=isbnvar)
        return render.book(book_details,price) # price is a global variable
```

**Edit**: My book template begins with -

```
$def with (book_details, price)
```

Going to /book/9876543210987 throws a `__template__() takes no arguments (2 given)` error. I can't figure what I'm doing wrong.

**Edit**: This is the full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 239, in process
    return self.handle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 230, in handle
    return self._delegate(fn, self.fvars, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 420, in _delegate
    return handle_class(cls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 396, in handle_class
    return tocall(*args)
  File "/home/chaitanya/justcompare/code.py", line 45, in GET
    return render.book(book_details,price)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/template.py", line 881, in __call__
    return BaseTemplate.__call__(self, *a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/template.py", line 808, in __call__
    return self.t(*a, **kw)
TypeError: __template__() takes no arguments (2 given)
```

Comment: Is `render` a template? What is it's definition?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't have a complete understanding of web.py yet. However from what I understand render is not a template. It is used to render a template which contains tags from the template language used by web.py (templetor) in the form of plain html.

Comment: @guy: Yes, but the file is still interpreted as a template; it'll pick the first `book.*` file as the template. Are there any other `book.*` files apart from `book.html`?

Comment: As a matter of fact there was a book.bak file that I had kept there as a backup of an old version. Thanks.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I know I should just move it (and I have) but I just wanted to know whether it is at all possible to keep two templates having the same names and different extensions?

Comment: @guy: You'd have to load them explicitly with `web.template.frender()` instead; `web.template.render` will only pick the first.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. You should post your comments above as an answer. I'll accept it. And it will probably help more people that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When rendering templates, web.py looks for a template file matching the provided name, using globbing. So, `render.book(...)` will look for a file starting with `book`. Specifically:

```
=== template.py ===
def _findfile(self, path_prefix):
    p = [f for f in glob.glob(path_prefix + '.*') if not f.endswith('~')]
    p.sort()  # sort the matches for deterministic order
    return p and p[0]
```

Which means it will use `book.a`, etc., before `book.html`, if they exist. `book.bak` isn't special, so it is preferred over `book.html`. Only files ending with `~` are skipped.

Note one more 'gotcha': If the (matching) template file ends with `.html`, `web.py` will automatically set the return's content type to `text/html`. The reason I bring this up is I find myself getting in the habit of naming template files ending with html, even if I want to return text or xml. Bad Habit. Name the `.html` if you want to return HTML content type. Name them `.txt` to return `text/plain`, name them `.xhtml` to return `application/xhtml+xml`. It's okay to name them `.json`, but you'll have to code your return headers to set content-type `application/json`.

In your case, as you've discovered, there's a `book.bak` in the directory which is cause the conflict/confusion.